# Mapping jersey Interface to particular network interface card (NIC)

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

I have two REST interfaces running in one container, let's call them *A* and *B*. 
I also have two network interface cards, *eth0* and *eth1*.
Given that I use Jersey/JAX-RS, is it at all possible to map REST I/F *A* to *eth0* and REST I/F *B* to *eth1*? Is there some sort of configuration/provider that I can use?

Comment: What is `eth0`/`eth1` on a Windows machine? I think, the maximum you can do is to bind to given IP address. But do not know, how you can do it...

Comment: These settings depend on deployment.. So maybe you should check deployment options...

Comment: If I understand it right, Jersey uses a system that is at least similar to `java.net.ServerSocket`. And that is identified by a `java.net.InetAddress`, which does accept an instance of `java.net.NetworkInterface`. So in some sense, what you want should be possible, you just need to find where is this configured in Jersey.

Comment: i would say this is the Container's responsibility, i think you can map each NIC to a certain virtual host (or web app) , what container are you using ?

Comment: @Yazan, I am using Karaf.

Comment: unfortunately i have no idea about it

Comment: I think that I'll investigate and see if it's possible to configure it on the container level instead. If not, I'll probably have to dig deeper into Jersey as suggested by @M.Prokhorov.